# Why does JSON.stringify ignore keys whose values are undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

To be more accurate, I understand *why* this technically happens - since `undefined` is not a valid JSON type:

```
var breakfast = {
    "cereal" : "fruit loops",
    "pastry" : undefined
};

console.log(breakfast);
// -> { cereal: 'fruit loops', pastry: undefined }

console.log(JSON.stringify(breakfast));
// -> {"cereal":"fruit loops"}
```

My question is - why is this considered acceptable behaviour? There are clearly valid reasons why I would want to pass `undefined` as part of an API or whatever. This seems somewhat dangerous - why wouldn't the function raise an error instead of brazenly taking it upon itself to change my data without warning? This seems like a bit of a running thread with JS.

Comment: JSON contains only strings. If a value is `undefined` it would also have to be converted to a string. What happens if I'm going to transfer a string which has the same value as the string-representation of `undefined`? How to distinguish which `"undefined"` is which. But if you really want to go this way then you can pass a `replacer` function as the second parameter of `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter

Comment: Like I said in the question, I understand the mechanics of what is going on - but I am unsatisfied as to why it does it. The function you link to is obviously a solution, but is not something that I believe should be required for this in the first place :)

Also as a side note, JSON contains other data types, not only strings (bools, arrays)

Comment: You're right for bools and numbers. But arrays are also translated into their string representation. `undefined` is not a defined value for [JSON](http://json.org/). If you really need to change the defined behaviour of JSON then you will have to use a `replacer` function.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't want to change the behaviour of JSON, I want to change the JSON.stringify method accordingly to reflect JSON's limitations. To clarify - I know how to do to this, what I'm saying is this should be default behaviour.

Comment: Seems to me this is actually a question for a JSON discussion group and has nothing to do with JavaScript (other than the J in JSON). Perhaps remove the *javascript* tag?

Comment: @RobG yeah possibly, i suppose it's still a js function? more of a discussionny thing tho i agree

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this lies in the [ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). In section `24.3.2 JSON.stringify ( value [ , replacer [ , space ] ] )`, the spec clearly states that:

> **NOTE 2**
>
> The **undefined** value is not rendered.

Further:

> **NOTE 5**
>
> Values that do not have a JSON representation (such as **undefined** and functions) do not produce a String. Instead they produce
>   the **undefined** value. In arrays these values are represented as the
>   String **null**. In objects an unrepresentable value causes the property
>   to be excluded from stringification.

**Thus, `JSON.stringify()` as you are using it is perfectly following the existing ECMA spec.**

Even using a replacer, without specifically specifying your own function, the default replacer rules state that *items* should only be appended:

> **24.3.2 Subsection 4.b.5.g**
>
> If *item* is not **undefined** and *item* is not currently an element of
>   *PropertyList*

Answer (score 6):

JSON is meant to be language agnostic. It already supports `null`. Supporting `undefined` as well would impose the handling of one of JavaScript's idiosyncrasies on other languages, which defeats the purpose of easy interoperability.

['JSON's design goals were for it to be minimal, portable, textual, and
   a subset of JavaScript.'](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

As for not throwing an error, well

```
var x = { foo: undefined };
x.foo === undefined; // true
var json = JSON.stringify(x);
var y = JSON.parse(json);
y.foo === undefined; // true
```

So `JSON.stringify` *can* create a string that represents the value `x`.
Throwing an error would not be useful in this case. In fact JSON.stringify
ignores all values that don't have a JSON representation, so functions
are ignored to. This makes it easy to serialise object data, for example.

Finally, bear in mind that JSON.stringify takes a `replacer` function as
an argument which can be used to alter the way stringification takes place.
So to make `JSON.stringify` throw existing properties with an `undefined` value:

```
var replacer = function(key, value){
    if(value === undefined){
        throw 'JSON.stringify: bad property: ' + key;
    }
    return value;
};

var x = {foo: undefined};
JSON.stringify(x, replacer);
// uncaught exception: JSON.stringify: bad property: foo
```

Or to replace with `null`:

```
var replacer = function(key, value){
    if(value === undefined){
        return null;
    }
    return value;
};

var x = {foo: undefined};
JSON.stringify(x, replacer); // '{"foo":null}'
```